# Java unexpected type doing string comparison, strange

Tags: java, string, multithreading

This code is exactly as it is in the book Learning Java (Oracle Press Books), but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't work, it should work. I've tried it with both OpenJDK and Sun JDK 7, the error is the same.

```
ThreadCom.java:56: error: unexpected type
    if (thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") = 0) {
                                ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

The code in question...

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    Thread thrd;
    TickTock ttOb;

    MyThread(String name, TickTock tt) {
            thrd = new Thread(this, name);
            ttOb = tt;
            thrd.start();
    }

    public void run() {
            if (thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") = 0) { // <- that line
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) ttOb.tick(true);
                    ttOb.tick(false);
            } else {
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) ttOb.tock(true);
                    ttOb.tock(false);
            }
    }
}
```

The code is exactly as it is in the book.

Comment: Hint: when the compiler gives a warning/error, switching JDK is about the *last* option to try. Because chances are *very* good that you are wrong, and the compiler is right. And that *doesn't* just apply to beginners, it applies to everybody ;-)

Answer (score 5):

this

```
thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") = 0
```

should be

```
thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") == 0
```

the first is an assignment. the second is a comparison.

Comment: I'm used to C++ where both work. What the hell is an assignment doing in an if? Is there something you can do in Java that is gained by being able to put an assignment in an if? The design of this language baffles me.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot the double equals, just noticed it.

```
if (thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") = 0)
```

should be

```
if (thrd.getName().compareTo("Tick") == 0)
```